# How to set vector drawable into EditText under api 21?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-vectordrawable

In my application i want show vector **drawable** right of `EditText`.
I added this **drawable** vector from **Vector Asset** into android studio!
but when run application show me force close error.
**Xml code :**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/signInFrag_phoneEdt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/insertYourPhoneNumber"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_phone_android"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_phone_android"/>
```

I added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` into `android` and `defaultConfig` on `gradle.build` file.

**error message :**

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_phone_android.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700b3
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:814)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:73)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.app
```

Also i added this line into **application** class :         `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to

```
app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_phone_android"
```

The support should be included in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your MainActivity

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
```